# How to change the default action for a file in Window 11 (w/o changing the default app)

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11

Sorry the question is longer than usual, but the shorter version would probably just close again because of a false "duplicate" stamp .

With "**default action**" Is meant the double click on a file in windows explorer or the click to the bolded action in the context menu of a file. "Default action" is not to be confused with "default app".

When I mention Notepad++ and .txt files it is only meant as an example. It is not a special solution for this searched but a general, which can be applied to each app and each file.

- This is **not** a duplicate to [How to change default action for file types?](https://superuser.com/questions/563706/how-to-change-default-action-for-file-types)
  because the question is over 10 yeas old and the answers are not the answers to my question and a lot has changed since then.
- This is **not** a duplicate to [How can I make Notepad++ default program for `.txt` files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1324367/how-can-i-make-notepad-default-program-for-txt-files) because, I don't want a solution only for Notepad++ and I don't want to change the default app!
- This is also **not** a duplicate to any question or answer to **How to change the default app**. because change the default app will change more as only the default action
- if someone comes up with a better title, I'm open to suggestions.

**I want to change the default action**, but I have found that **changing the default application** is **not** the solution to this because changing the default application will:

- change the icon
- change the context menu action
- change the "open with "suggestions
- change "send to"
- etc. ... short: it will change too much

In older windows versions you simply searched the registry for the extension (.txt) then the default entry (txtfile) and created or changed shell/open/command.

But this seems not to work in Windows 11 (at least not everywhere). Sometimes the entry does not exist, sometimes it is ignored.

BTW: what new registry keys do I need to know?

Shows that the "assign default app" is not the solution:

- create a new file "test.specialtxt"
- add Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.specialtxt@default=specialtxtfile
- add specialtxtfile structure: shell/open/command + shell/special/command
- Test in Explorer that the context menu items "open" and "special" appear
- assign Notepad as default app. (open with... always)
- **"open" and "special" disappear**
- assign Notepadd++ as default app.
- still **"open" and "special" disappear**
- now specialtxt_auto_file is assigned to .specialtxt
  Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.specialtxt@default=specialtxt_auto_file

**So what can I do to change the default action without changing other things?**